# JSON.parse: unexpected end of data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Code below works fine in my local machine (WAMP) but always fails on live LINUX machine with this error: **JSON.parse: unexpected end of data**

Is it to do with environment or I'm missing something? I looked at other posts but failed to solve the problem.

I'm using jquery 1.8.0 version.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#run").click(function(event)
   {
      $('#run').hide();
      $('#loader').fadeIn(1000);

      $.ajax(
      {
         type       : 'POST',
         url        : 'process.php',
         data       : 'user=jolly',
         dataType   : 'json',
         success        : function(response)
         {
             $('#loader').stop(true).fadeOut(function ()
             {
                  if (response.status == 'goodjob')
                  {
                      $('#tick').fadeIn(1000, function ()
                      {
                          $('#script').fadeIn(1000);
                      });
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $('#cross').fadeIn(1000);
                  }
              });
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
          {
              alert(textStatus + '---' + errorThrown);
          }
      });
   });
});


<div id="first">
   <img id="run" src="run.png" />
   <img id="loader" src="loader.png" style="display:none;" />
   <img id="success" src="success.png" style="display:none;" />
   <img id="fail" src="fail.png" style="display:none;" />
</div>
<div id="next" style="display:none;">
   ....
   ....
</div>
```

**process.php**

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'goodjob'));
```

Comment: did you compare those 2 outputs? sounds like a server problem

Comment: If you use a HTTP packet debugger such as Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), or Chrome's inbuilt network tab (CTRL+SHIFT+J) can you see what string your linux sends back?

Comment: FF - parseerror --- SyntaxError JSON.parse: unexpected end of data, CHROME - parseerror --- SyntaxError : Unxpected end of input. Also CHROME network tab has -> Method:POST, Status:200 OK, Type:text/html, Initiator: jquery-1.8.0.js:8214 ..........

Comment: It sounds like you may have some other data being sent by your PHP program other than just the JSON string which is making it invalid. You've been to the Chrome network tab; take a look at the 'response' tab inside there to see what the actual data being received looks like to the browser. If you can't see a problem there, may be try pasting this actual output into the question so we can see it.